# Create conditional resource in terraform after count is already used

Tags: terraform, amazon-route53, terraform0.12+

I am creating a route53 healthcheck for each service in a given value of `services` string variable.

My `tfvars` file looks like below when I pass the value for the services variable

`services = "servicea serviceb serviced"`

I would only need to make these healthchecks if `var.env == prod`.

There is tried and tested method to use and that would be using `count = var.env == prod ? 1:0` but as I am already using count to calculate and iterate over the services string, I am not able to use `count` again in the same resource block, as terraform 0.12 is giving me following error message if I am trying to do so.

**Error while using multiple count in same resource block**

```
Error: Attribute redefined

  on <stdin> line 514:   (source code not available)

The argument "count" was already set at <stdin>:513,2-7. Each argument may be set only once.
```

**Terraform Configuration**

```
variable "services" {
  default = ""
}


resource aws_route53_health_check "app_healthcheck" {
  count             = length(split(",", replace(var.services, "/\\s/", ",")))
  fqdn              = "${var.super_cluster}-${var.region}.domainname.com"
  port              = 443
  type              = "HTTPS"
  resource_path     = "/canSchedule?appName=${element(split(",", replace(var.services, "/\\s/", ",")), count.index)}"
  request_interval  = "10"
  failure_threshold = "1"
  enable_sni        = true
  tags              = local.common_tags


}
```

How can I create conditional resource , once `count` has been used in resource block ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To work around this you can introduce a new local to check the value of the env variable:

```
locals {
  is_prod = var.env == "prod" ? true : false
}
```

And then in your resource block use that local in a conditional expression like this:

`count = local.is_prod ? length(split(",", replace(var.services, "/\\s/", ","))) : 0`

Comment: Your solution worked ! But I am curious to know the use case of locals here. I thought to use that before but if my understanding is correct locals should be only use when you want to take out the repetition from TF config ! As you can see from my code above I am already using local.common_tags to propagate tags everywhere in my resources.

Comment: You're right, and to avoid repetitions is exactly what locals are meant for, according to the [TF docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html). But there is no harm in using them only once when it helps us to overcome a TF limitation/restriction ;)

Comment: This could have been written without a local value too: `count = var.env == "prod" ? length(split(",", replace(var.services, "/\\s/", ","))) : 0`. Using a local value can sometimes improve readability by simplifying an expression to something more intuitive, like this "is prod" flag, but that's a style tradeoff rather than a Terraform limitation.